# how to reply a professor is not available for research guidance

Tags: research-process, communication

> Thanks for your interest. But I am not available for guidance or mentorship.

This is my professor's reply.

I don't know how to reply back formally. I want to know if this professor can suggest my name to his colleagues. I don't how to formally ask him to do this.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: What concretely is your question? Are you asking for someone else to write an email for you? I think you know what you want to say, just say it!

Comment: Is this a professor at your institution?  Do you have some existing relationship with him?  Or is he a stranger that you contacted out of the blue?  If the latter, this is a flat refusal and you should not reply.

Answer (score 6):

**You should not reply to this at all.** He has made it abundantly clear that he is not interested in helping you in any capacity. This is actually nice of him: many professors would not reply at all, or would make promises and then not follow through.

> I want to know if this professor can suggest my name to his colleagues.

Consider just approaching his colleagues yourself. Or, if you have the opportunity to speak to this professor in person (e.g., office hours), you could ask then if they could recommend someone to advise you. But replying to this e-mail is unlikely to have the desired effect.

Comment: OP should ask themselves why they think that going through this professor is preferable to talk to the colleagues directly. Do they know this professor, but not the colleagues?